# How to specify multiple jar files in oozie

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I need a solution for the following problem:
My project has two jars in which

one jar contains all bean classes like Employee etc, and the other jar contains MR jobs which uses the first jar bean class so when iam trying to run the MR job as a simple java program i am facing the issue of class not found (com.abc.Employee class not found as it is in another jar) so can any one provide me the solution how to solve the issue ....  as in real time there may be many jars not 1 or 2 how to specify all those jars can any one please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a `lib` folder in the HDFS directory where you are storing your Oozie workflow. You can place both jar files in this folder and oozie will ensure both are on the classpath when your MR job executes:

```
hdfs://namenode:8020/path/to/oozie/app/workflow.xml
hdfs://namenode:8020/path/to/oozie/app/lib/first.jar
hdfs://namenode:8020/path/to/oozie/app/lib/second.jar
```

See [Workflow Application Deployment](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a7_Workflow_Application_Deployment) for more details

If you often use jars in a number of oozie workflows, you can place these common jars (HBase jars for example) in a directory in HDFS, and then denote in an oozie property to include this folder's jars See [HDFS Share Libraries](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a17_HDFS_Share_Libraries_for_Workflow_Applications_since_Oozie_2.3) for more details

Comment: I did the same but it is throwing an exception that class not found

Comment: I had done it but it is throwing classnotfound exception even though the class is present

Comment: The class not found isn't inside a jar-in-a-jar is it? This won't work as oozie doesn't unpack the jars (hence exposing the jars-in-jar).

Comment: This answer is not correct. I had a jar compiled for a scala job and the normal working java job jar. These 2 were not intermingling well. It was throwing classnotfound exception because the first jar was there in lib directory. When I moved this out to another then it worked.