# How do I specify multiple libpath in oozie job?

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, oozie

My oozie job uses 2 jars **x.jar** and **y.jar** and following is my job.properties file.

```
oozie.libpath=/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
```

This works perfectly when both the jars are present at same location on HDFS at  **/lib/x.jar** and **/lib/y.jar**

Now I have 2 jars placed at different locations **/lib/1/x.jar** and **/lib/2/y.jar**.
How can I re-write my code such that both the jars are used while running the map reduce job?
**Note:** I have already refernced the answer [How to specify multiple jar files in oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720610/how-to-specify-multiple-jar-files-in-oozie) but, this does not solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer at 
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/
Turns out that I can specify multiple paths separated by comma in the job.properties file:

```
oozie.libpath=/path/to/jars,another/path/to/jars
```